# Symfony4 - 404 with routes of vendors bundles

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I am testing Symfony 4 in a docker container.

The default symfony app works well, but I have some issues with routing
I have installed profiler and easyAdmin, but it seems routing of those bundles are note working in my case.

However, when the command php bin/console debug:router return :
[image]

Neither the admin or profiler url are working, both are 404

Thanks,

Comment: - I do not have a .htaccess in my public folder.

- The error seems to be sent by apache, not by symfony, but the symfony favicon is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was the missing .htaccess file, in the public folder.

I copy/paste and adpat the one from symfony 3.4, mainly by replacing app_ by index

Comment: Server configuration can easily be found in the official documentation :  https://symfony.com/doc/master/setup/web_server_configuration.html